# How to match a specific value to a specified range of integer?

Tags: sql-server

I have tables which stores loan schedules, please note that I only extracted 1 id from the schedule table

Table: **Schedule**

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|ID           |   Date      | Amount    |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| H 1807.0030 | 2020-10-25  | 338850.00 |
| H 1807.0030 | 2020-11-25  | 301200.00 |
| H 1807.0030 | 2020-12-25  | 263550.00 |
| H 1807.0030 | 2021-01-25  | 225900.00 |
| H 1807.0030 | 2021-02-25  | 188250.00 | > Compare2
| H 1807.0030 | 2021-03-25  | 150600.00 | > Compare1
| H 1807.0030 | 2021-04-25  | 112950.00 | > Compare3
| H 1807.0030 | 2021-05-25  | 75300.00  |
| H 1807.0030 | 2021-06-25  | 37650.00  |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want something like this:

Match 1:

*IF Balance = Schedules.Amount it should return Date "2021-03-25"*

```
+-------------+-----------+
|ID           | Balance   |
+-------------+-----------+
| H 1807.0030 | 150600.00 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Match 2:

*IF Balance > Schedules.Amount and lesser than Compare2 it should still return Date "2021-03-25"*

```
+-------------+-----------+
|ID           | Balance   |
+-------------+-----------+
| H 1807.0030 | 150800.00 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Match 3:

IF Balance < Schedules.Amount and greater than Compare3 it should return Date "2021-04-255"

```
+-------------+-----------+
|ID           | Balance   |
+-------------+-----------+
| H 1807.0030 | 113950.00 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

What I have tried:

```
OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP(1) LoanId, DatePayment,InterestBalance, TotalBalance 
      FROM LoanSchedules where LoanID = loans.LoanID
          AND TotalBalance = scheduleofaccountscurrentlr.Balance --##Comparison
      ORDER BY DatePayment DESC
) tmpschedintbal
```

But it only returns the date of two match amount. Any suggestion of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the final results to be?

Comment: @vvvv4d I have included a match samples in my question. If balance exist in schedule table.

Comment: is there a `datetime` or `date` column on the balances table? Can you provide the structure of the other table. You shared the complete definition of one Schedule table and minimal details about the other.

Comment: @vvvv4d only the amount.

Comment: How do you know what row is Compare1 versus Compare2 verus Compare3? they are not in order sequentially going 2, 1, 3. Can you help describe that logic?

Comment: What are the expected results? Will this be the separate three results or should return one of the cases matches ?

Comment: @Manu return one of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to select the `Date` that corresponds with the `Amount` that is equal to or less than a given `Balance`. In case no equal `Amount` is found, then the closest `Amount` below `Balance` must be picked.

**Sample data**

```
create table Schedule
(
  ID nvarchar(11),
  Date date,
  Amount money
);

insert into Schedule (ID, Date, Amount) values
('H 1807.0030', '2020-10-25', 338850.00),
('H 1807.0030', '2020-11-25', 301200.00),
('H 1807.0030', '2020-12-25', 263550.00),
('H 1807.0030', '2021-01-25', 225900.00),
('H 1807.0030', '2021-02-25', 188250.00),
('H 1807.0030', '2021-03-25', 150600.00),
('H 1807.0030', '2021-04-25', 112950.00),
('H 1807.0030', '2021-05-25', 75300.00 ),
('H 1807.0030', '2021-06-25', 37650.00 );

create table Ledger
(
  Example int,
  ID nvarchar(11),
  Balance money
);

insert into Ledger (Example, ID, Balance) values
(1, 'H 1807.0030', 150600.00), -- expect 2021-03-25
(2, 'H 1807.0030', 150800.00), -- expect 2021-03-25
(3, 'H 1807.0030', 113950.00); -- expect 2021-04-25
```

**Solution**

```
select l.Example,
       l.ID,
       l.Balance,
       x.Date
from Ledger l
cross apply (  select top 1 s.Date
               from Schedule s
               where s.ID = l.ID
                 and s.Amount-l.Balance <= 0
               order by s.Amount-l.Balance desc ) x
order by l.Example;
```

**Result**

```
Example  ID           Balance      Date
-------- ------------ ------------ -----------
1        H 1807.0030  150600.0000  2021-03-25
2        H 1807.0030  150800.0000  2021-03-25
3        H 1807.0030  113950.0000  2021-04-25
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee8dfbed47d5bbf263ef954a833a8f88)